# Что такое контекст? Более обширный взгляд

Tags: android, context

Сколько уже разрабатываю приложения, до сих пор не понимаю что такое контекст. Например, возьмем старый добрый `Toast`

```
 Toast.makeText(context, String, int);
```

Первый параметр статического метода `makeText` класса `Toast` - это контекст. Но я могу передать `this` (если вызов метода находится не дальше одного блока кода) или `MainActivity.this` (если имя класса-активности `MainActivity`), могу также передать `getApplicationContext()`.

- Так в чем разница?
- Почему в качестве контекста можно передать `this`? Это же ссылка на класс
- Есть ли случаи когда надо передать именно `getApplicationContext`?
- Почему контекст нужен везде, где происходит работа с интерфейсом?
- Почему любой виджет имеет конструктор, в который надо передать контекст?
- Что вообще такое контекст?

Последний вопрос я задал, так как по ходу написания остальных, я понял, что ничего о нем не знаю :)

Comment: Стандартные библиотеки языка очень образные и что бы понять семантику контекста надо прежде всего обратиться к самому понятию "контекст" в общепринятом понимании, а не в специфике программирования: _Конте́кст (от лат. contextus — «соединение», «связь») — законченный отрывок, общий смысл которого позволяет уточнить значение входящих в него отдельных слов, предложений, и т. п. _
_Говорить, опираясь на контекст, — значит придерживаться установившегося в разговоре уровня абстракции и использовать понятия заданного в нём семантического поля._

Comment: _В более широком значении контекст — среда, в которой существует объект.
С формальной точки зрения контекст представляет собой определённую систему отсчета, пространство имён.
Любое событие, происходящее в жизни субъекта, интерпретируется исходя из контекста ситуации, отражённой в памяти субъекта._

Comment: В программировании понятие _контекст_ имеет те же свойства и семантическую нагрузку - давать элементу переменные окружения, обуславливающие его работу

Comment: (: А по вопросу мне нечего ответить

Comment: @Tachkin, отличный ответ :) Я плюсану, оформляйте. :)

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, я ни на один из вопросов не ответил. Точнее ответил, но на какой то другой вопрос :) Я в android и не понимаю ничего :)

Comment: @Tachkin, суть контекста все равно та же, остальное детали имплементации.

Comment: @Tachkin можно использовать даже как описание метки

Answer (score 11, accepted):

класс `Context` содержит в себе всевозможную информацию о ресурсах системы, как уже было сказано в другом ответе. Конкретно в этом вопросе нас интересует, что он содержит, помимо прочего, и параметры темы (стилей) для отображения `View`

> Почему в качестве контекста можно передать this? Это же ссылка на класс

Активити является наследником класса `Context` и несет в себе информацию о контексте для этой активити, поэтому мы можем использовать ссылку на именно этот класс в качестве контекста. С `Fragment`, к примеру, это уже не работает - он не наследуется от `Context`

> Есть ли случаи когда надо передать именно getApplicationContext?

Тема (стиль) всего приложения и конкретной активити может отличаться (для активити в манифесте указан другой стиль). Тогда запрос контекста приложения и контекста активти вернет разное оформление `View`

> Почему контекст нужен везде, где происходит работа с интерфейсом?

Потому что он содержит стиль для `View`

на остальные вопросы ответ тот же - в контексте содержится информация, как должен выглядеть `View`. Например, стиль кнопки темы *Holo* и темы *AppCompat* сильно отличается, в контексте и содержится эта информация.

Возможно в приложении могут существовать и какие то другие отличия в окружении, назначенном всему приложению и конкретной активити, тогда обращение к контексту приложения или активити тоже будет иметь значение, но мне такие отличия (кроме тем и стилей) припомнить не удалось.

**UPD** несколько важных замечаний по `getApplicationContext()`, не связанных с UI приложения из [этой статьи](https://blog.mindorks.com/understanding-context-in-android-application-330913e32514)

1. контекст приложения следует использовать везде, где контекст необходимо передать за пределы жизненного цикла передающего компонента (в объекты, которые будут жить дольше, чем создавшая/вызвавшая их активность, например) во избежании удержания ссылки на этот компонент при использовании его собственного контекста и утечек памяти.
2. во внешние библиотеки следует передавать контекст приложения по тем же причинам, что и п.1
3. контекст приложения не имеет информации по особенностям GUI отдельной активити, если они отличаются от параметров всего приложения, в таких случаях нельзя использовать контекст приложения при работе с GUI этой активити.
4. приложение (класс `Application`) - синглтон и его контекст тоже синглтон, этот контекст может удерживать объекты с более коротким жизненным циклом и приводить к утечкам памяти, если не позаботиться о их корректной обработке GC

Comment: `Это же ссылка на класс`, `ссылку на именно этот класс` -- или на объект класса?

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Объект класса `Activity` создается (и создается ли вообще) системой и скрыт от прикладного программиста. В контексте этого вопроса данное обстоятельство не имеет особого значения, но если присмотреться, то вызывается `MainActivity.this` - следовательно все же класс, а не объект класса.

Comment: при всем уважении, не согласен. Oracle говорит, что "`this` is a reference to the current object". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html

Comment: И сам объект класса `Activity` совсем не скрыт, процесс создания да. Программист не может создавать активити напрямую, может только посылать интенты системе, чтобы она создала. Но уже созданный объект в полном его распоряжении.

Answer (score 5):

В исходниках класса копаться не пробовали?

> Interface to global information about an application environment. This is
>    an abstract class whose implementation is provided by
>    the Android system.  It
>    allows access to application-specific resources and classes, as well as
>    up-calls for application-level operations such as launching activities,
>    broadcasting and receiving intents, etc. [источник (2 ссылка запроса "context android" в Google)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html)

Если всё ещё не понятно:

> Context – это объект, который предоставляет доступ к базовым функциям приложения: доступ к ресурсам, к файловой системе, вызов активности и т.д. Activity является подклассом Context, поэтому в коде мы можем использовать её как ИмяАктивности.this (напр. MainActivity.this), или укороченную запись this. Классы Service, Application и др. также работают с контекстом. [источник (1 ссылка запроса "context android" в Google!!!)](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/context.php)

Идеальный ответ на все Ваши вопросы.

Comment: Спасибо. Да, знаю, гуглить я могу, просто решил тут спросить

Comment: Так никто и не ответил на вторую часть вопроса: что такое `ApplicationContext` и чем он отличается от обычного `Context`

Comment: @Barmaley, а что тут отвечать? `Context` абстрактный класс, `ApplicationContext` его имплементация.

Comment: Чем имплементация в виде `Activity` отличается от имплементации в виде `Application`, вот что интересно.