# Что такое Context ?

Tags: java, android

Если можно то по простому и желательно с примером.

Comment: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/context.php

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/643251/177345

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Контекст - это среда в которой происходит работа/выполнение чего-то.

Примеры:

- *хочу есть* - контекст: офис - иду в столовую/кафе
- *хочу есть* - контекст: дом - открываю холодильник
- *хочу есть* - контекст: улица - покупаю хот дог в палатке

Аналогично и с Android, `Context` предоставляет доступ к неким ресурсам, файловой системе, виджетам и т.д., но поскольку контекст каждый раз разный, то и доступ к ресурсам каждый раз немного отличается.